# How do I remove the numbers displayed for lines on a mesh when you "A" a mesh?

Tags: mesh

Alright, so I've created mesh files before. For some reason I keep seeing numbers on all the lines when I select my mesh. How do I remove that display so I can't see it?

Comment: Nvm, tinkered and realized had to deselect checkboxes for Edge/Face info under "N."

Comment: could you add a bit more to your answer. A picture of that section of the properties panel would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, tinkered and realized had to deselect checkboxes for Edge/Face info under "N."